# Meteor raix push notification lost due to no connection

Tags: meteor, push-notification

I am using [push](https://github.com/raix/push) notifications in meteor app for ios and android. It works fine if the users to whom I am sending the notifications are connected to the internet. The problem that if I send a notification to an offline user and when he connects to the internet after few hours, the notification is not delivered. Any insights as how to overcome this.
Following is my code to send notifications :

```
Push.send({
    from: '1234',
    title: title,
    text: text,
    notId : nId,
    gcm: {
        title: title,
        style:  'inbox',
    },
    query: {
        userId: {
            $in: userIds
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: I couldn't find TTL(Time To Live) option in the gitRepo you provided.. usually there is an option for that.. You can read more about that here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Including TTL solved the issue for me. Please post this as an answer and I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Its good that your is resolved.. Please share it so others who ran into same problem can get help :)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find TTL(Time To Live) option in the gitRepo you provided.. usually there is an option for that.. You can read more about that here  <strike>[concept options](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options)</strike>

**Update**
[New Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#delivery_options)

> ***Lifetime of a message*** 
> When an app server posts a message to FCM and
>   receives a message ID back, it does not mean that the message was
>   already delivered to the device. Rather, it means that it was accepted
>   for delivery. What happens to the message after it is accepted depends
>   on many factors.
>
> In the best-case scenario, if the device is connected to FCM, the
>   screen is on and there are no throttling restrictions, the message is
>   delivered right away.
>
> If the device is connected but in Doze, a low priority message is
>   stored by FCM until the device is out of Doze. And that's where the
>   `collapse_key` flag plays a role: if there is already a message with the
>   same collapse key (and registration token) stored and waiting for
>   delivery, the old message is discarded and the new message takes its
>   place (that is, the old message is collapsed by the new one). However,
>   if the collapse key is not set, both the new and old messages are
>   stored for future delivery.
>
> If the device is not connected to FCM, the message is stored until a
>   connection is established (again respecting the collapse key rules).
>   When a connection is established, FCM delivers all pending messages to
>   the device. If the device never gets connected again (for instance, if
>   it was factory reset), the message eventually times out and is
>   discarded from FCM storage. The default timeout is four weeks, unless
>   the `time_to_live` flag is set.
>
> To get more insight into the delivery of a message:
>
> 1. For Android and iOS: See the FCM reporting dashboard, which records
>      the number of messages sent and opened on iOS and Android devices,
>      along with data for "impressions" (notifications seen by users) for
>      Android apps.
> 2. For Android: If you'd like to be notified when the application
>      successfully receives a message, you can use
>      delivery_receipt_requested functionality following the guidelines.
>      This requires you to setup an XMPP server.
> 3. For Android, iOS and Web: You can use InstanceID APIs to check the
>      most recent date that the device you're targeting through the FCM
>      registration token has established a connection with FCM.